# Excluding files/directories from WAR packaging in Grails 3

Tags: grails, gradle, build.gradle, grails-3.1

In my Grails 3.1.10 app, I have a few files in `src/main/webapp/ng` directory for an Angular app and I want to exclude few of the directories/files from packaging to the WAR file at the time of `grails package` command.

In Grails 2.x app, we have achieved it via `BuildConfig.groovy` setting:

```
grails.war.resources = { stagingDir, args ->
    delete(dir: "${stagingDir}/ng/node_modules")
    delete(dir: "${stagingDir}/ng/app")
    delete(dir: "${stagingDir}/ng/bower_components")
}
```

How can we achieve that in Grails 3? I tried searching for it but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I realized later that Grails 3 is using Gradle and Grails 2 was using Ant task. So I searched the same issue of excluding stuff in Gradle since Grails 3 uses Gradle's [WAR plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/war_plugin.html) and from the docs:

> Of course one can configure the different file-sets with a closure to
>   define excludes and includes.

Here is the solution to exclude files in Grails 3 from packaging.

Put the following in the `build.gradle` file of your Grails 3 application:

```
war {
    exclude("ng/node_modules")
    exclude("ng/bower_components")
    exclude("ng/app")
    exclude("ng/*.tar.gz")
    exclude("ng/.*")       // For example: exclude all the hidden files
}
```